# Django admin - stackedInline single instance

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm building a site based on a highly customized django admin instance and am running into issues with user profiles as an inline to user_admin

long story short regardless of what I set for max_num and extra in the admin.StackedInline instance it allows up to 2 profiles per user - with a blank one in place by default if the user has an existing profile

anyone know how I could adjust this to show only a single inline profile without resorting to some JS front end hack?

relevant code from: profiles.admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from profile.models import user_profile

class user_profile_admin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = user_profile

    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    extra = 0

class user_admin_extended(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [user_profile_admin, ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, user_admin_extended)
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using FK field to connect user and profile? Try OneToOneField it should render just one inline in admin.